# How to open a React Native app using a deep link from an email, WhatsApp chat or social media?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs

I know that we have a lot of content of how to open deep links internally in a React Native app, for example using something like `mychat://profile/:username` will open a specific user profile, but how can I open that specific profile using an external URL?

For example, what if I want to share my profile via WhatsApp? I've tried using my registered `host` in the `/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` file as the oficial docs says (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking/) using my prefixes and sending something like `www.myuchat.com/profile/:username` but is not working.

So, how can a deep link be accessed from another app or location so I can open my app deep links from emails, WhatsApp, social media etc?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Deep Linking is a technique in which a given URL or resource is used to open a specific page or screen on mobile. So, instead of just launching the app on mobile, a deep link can lead a user to a specific screen within the app, providing a better user experience. This particular screen may reside under a series of hierarchical pages, hence the term "deep" in deep linking.

Refer to this link for Deeplink :
https://blog.jscrambler.com/how-to-handle-deep-linking-in-a-react-native-app

Comment: Yes, that link follows the same that I already did with the official docs but my question is very clear, I need to open my app on a specific screen but externally, from WhatsApp, Facebook, etc?